# About to expire Canadian visa

Tags: visas, passport-renewals, visa-renewals

I hold a valid Indian passport. My passport expires on 29 September 2020; my Canadian visa also expires on 29 September 2020.

I am getting my passport renewed next month as I will be travelling to Europe in May, and to Canada from June to August.

So my query is: will the Canadian visa in the old passport be valid for my travel to Canada, or do I have to get a new valid visa?